# Django Angular JS integration

Tags: angularjs, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a django working app in which I use a terminal command to display a database, this command is written in a function inside models.py

In addition, I have an html template that uses angular.js to display 3 text boxes.(fields, ID, Date, Source)

This all works, but what I want to do is to be able to use what the user inputs in these 3 text boxes as the the 3 variables to be used in the models.py, currently I have to write the whole command manually in models.py

The problem is that I know how to borrow from models.py using angular.js but not the other way around.

Any suggestions?

Lev

Comment: If you're going to use AngularJS then I'd recommend using http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ to interface between Django and Angular.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback, I followed that. But as I said it works if you use a django model inside angular.js, what I want to be able to do is use angular.js inside a django model

Comment: AngularJS is frontend, Django is backend. What you're asking for is to put frontend code into the backend? That doesn't really make sense. You should probably reconsider what you're trying to accomplish.